# I want to do something on a specific path change in react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Although I am aware of it.

```js
props.history.listen((location, action) => {
                     console.log("on route change",location);
                   })
```

But I need to implement slightly different.
let's say I want to do something on a specific path change in react router.
example-  **/user** to **/dashboard**.
On destination component  I want to do something(state change) if the previous path was   **/user**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In user page, you can push with state. For example,

```
history.push({
    pathname:'/dashboard',
    state: { someState: someState }
});
```

And in dashboard page, you can get the state by location:

```
console.log(props.location.state);
```

Comment: in the destination component console.log(props.location.state);
it is showing undefined.

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of the the `history` prop when you are using `react-router`.

```
props.history.push('/dashboard');
```

It can be used to track previous routes and `push` method to redirect user to the desired path.

Take a look at https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history